# Difference between creating NFT with Opensea and with solidity code

Tags: nft, gas-price, opensea

You can create and list your NFTs without any coding using OpenSea or you can create and put it on OpenSea using solidity code (smart contracts, ERC-721, or ERC-1155). Why would anyone want to deal with the coding when there is an easy UI? To be more specific: What are the advantages to choose one over another?

Answer (score 1):

It's a trade-off between customizability and ease of use. If you just want to list some NFT using Opensea's contract, you can use the UI. If you want to add some special features or customise any part of the NFT contract, you can deploy your own solidity contract too. It all depends on the usecase.

Comment: That's a good answer but I was looking for an in-depth explanation, things like what are the "special features" or "customizations" are missing in the OpenSea. maybe I should've been more explicit about this. I'll edit the question according to that.

Comment: There isn't any exhaustive list of special features. But for example, let's say you want to create an NFT that contains the asset on-chain (ex [ArtBlocks](https://www.artblocks.io/learn), that won't be possible via default Opensea NFT contracts. Another example would be derivative projects, that build on other NFT projects. QUite a few derivative projects were build based on the Loot project. You can find a few of them [here](https://www.lootwatcher.com/).